# Password reset endpoint always returns 401 error

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are trying to use the Admin API to reset customer passwords however that endpoint always returned a 401 error.

We are using the OAuth Client Credential flow and are sending the Authorization Bearer header. The authentication is working fine on the User Search, User Detail, and User Status API calls but always fails on the password reset endpoint.

The Associated user has "Manage everything" permissions and if I login to Banno as the associated user I am able to send password reset links without issue.

```
x-request-id: 1027f61b488670cf8f9d0f8af5abe85a
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2022 18:52:05 GMT
Client ID: d2970973-1929-4053-abd6-701d188e9945
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this problem with my own user. However, the `x-request-id` is useful and I will track this down with the Engineering team.

Comment: Can you give it another attempt? Engineering has deployed new code that it believes will fix the issue.

Comment: Still getting the 401 error.  Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2022 15:04:50 GMT,  x-request-id: aad84b2e5d2cc3fb671a58c677f58337

Comment: Thank you for the `x-request-id`. We'll have Engineering take a look.

Comment: Can you try again? Engineering has deployed new code for this.

Comment: Now I'm getting a 404 error.  I know the institution ID and user ID are correct because I can successfully use the same values for the User Details and User status API endpoints. Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2022 17:39:06 GMT x-request-id: 333cdc1449883aa4fec832d90de71320

Comment: Engineering has deployed another fix. Please try again and let us know if this fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Looks like that did the trick!  Thanks for the help.